# Change Sublime Text 3 Sidebar Width

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I wanted to know if it is possible to change the sidebar width in ST3? Is this a project based, theme based, or something in settings? I did not see in default settings so that is why I brought the question here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resize the sidebar, all you need to do is click and drag:

[image]

There is no way to set a "default" size in your user preferences, project, or current theme, unfortunately.

Comment: Ha, so much for not being able to see this with the skin I was trying. Thank you :-)